# How to get consistent results when using RNFS.touch for setting the modification date?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-fs

I'm updating the modification time of a file, and I'm getting some inconsistencies while converting back and forth from mtime to UNIX.

The timestamps are provided by an API which uses PostgreSQL and Sequelize for storing documents.

So an example would be when I'm trying to convert this specific timestamp `1569484561772`.

```
const updatedAt = 1569484561772;
await RNFS.downloadFile({
  fromUrl: url,
  toFile: path
}).promise;
const date = new Date(updatedAt);
await RNFS.touch(path, date);
const stat = await RNFS.stat(templatePath);

console.log(stat.mtime.getTime()); // 1569484561771
console.log(date.getTime()); // 1569484561772
```

Then if I'm logging `stat.mtime.getTime()` and date.getTime(), I'm getting **1569484561771** and **1569484561772** respectively, but I expect them to be the same timestamp. This doesn't happen with all timestamps, this is one example timestamp which behaves in this way.

Comment: I have implemented a temporary workaround, basically rounding the timestamp to second precision (```Math.round(timestamp / 1000) * 1000```), since I just need the timestamps to match and not the millisecond precision